# Get Wordpress posts by tag in Ruby

Tags: ruby, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

We have a Wordpress instance with the XML-RPC API enabled and a Ruby on Rails website we want to display Wordpress posts on. I need to get posts by "tag". Looking at Rubypress it seems as though I have to `wp.getPosts` and parse out the correct ones. This is inefficient as we add new posts and have to keep updating.

Is there a way to get posts from a Wordpress instance via the API by tag?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this with the `wp_api_client` gem and using the `tags?slug=TAG` endpoint. e.g.

```
require 'wp_api_client'
WpApiClient.configure do |api_client|
    api_client.endpoint = "yourwordpress.com/wp-json/wp/v2"
    api_client.basic_auth = {username: username, password: password}
end
client = WpApiClient.get_client
client.get("tags?slug=#{tag_you_want}").each do |tag|
    client.get("posts?tags=#{tag.id}")
end
```